# How can I easily customize the XML input files of the Curriculum Course example of OptaPlanner?

Tags: java, xml, input, optaplanner

I'm quite a beginner for not only OptaPlanner but also Java, which I started to learn two weeks ago. I am considering to start with modifying an example accompanied with the source program to make a scheduler for my present project.

**Target**

The XML input file of the “Curriculum Course” example of RedHat OptaPlanner

**Question**

Is there any easy way to modify the XML input files or add customized ones?

**Example data**

*Original XML: optaplanner-examples/data/curriculumcourse/unsolved/comp01.xml*

```
<CourseSchedule id="1">
...
  <curriculumList id="27">
    <Curriculum id="28">
      <code>q000</code>
    </Curriculum>
...
  <courseList id="42">
    <Course id="43">
      <curriculumList id="44">
        <Curriculum reference="28"/>
        <Curriculum reference="30"/>
      </curriculumList>
    </Course>
...
  </courseList>
...
</CourseSchedule>
```

The problem is that I have to renumber all the ID numbers every time I change the length of any lists. 
In the “Curriculum Course” example, I can find the corresponding .ctt files that are easy to change using a common text editor. The following is input data that I want to create expressed in the .ctt format:

*.ctt modified from: optaplanner-examples/data/curriculumcourse/import/comp01.ctt*

```
Name: Test01
Courses: 3
Rooms: 3
Days: 5
Periods_per_day: 13
Curricula: 3
Constraints: 0

COURSES:
c0001 t000 5 99 1
c0002 t001 5 99 1
c0003 t002 5 99 1

ROOMS:
P01 999
P02 999
P03 999

CURRICULA:
q001  1 c0001
q002  1 c0002
q003  1 c0003

UNAVAILABILITY_CONSTRAINTS:

END.
```

I wonder some tools could convert this text data into the XML files specific to the “Curriculum Course” example.

Comment: Maybe if you can specify more explicitly what you're trying to achieve, people who are not familiar with that learning platform can help you as well.

Comment: Dear liacqu, thank you very much for your writing advice. Using stackoverflow was also the first-time experience to me. Previously, I had one misunderstanding about this system itself. I hope the added data examples can clarify what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you click "Import..." button of the application, you can load the .ctt file and solve it. You don't need to convert .ctt to .xml. So there should be no problem for you to place your own xxx.ctt file under data/curriculumcourse/import and let the app import it.